# Template specialization no matching constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I am creating a templated vector class that is roughly done in the following way:

```
// Main class
template <typename T, int DIMS>
class Vector
{
    // Default constructor
    Vector();
    // Data constructor
    Vector(const T data[DIMS]);

    // Other functions, variables, operators
};

// 3d specialization
template <typename T>
class Vector<T, 3>
{
    // Cross product for 3d vectors -- only thing in specialization
    static Vector<T, 3> cross(const Vector<T, 3> a, const Vector<T, 3> b);
};
```

For the main template, I have a default constructor as well as a constructor specifying the elements. When I try to compile using the constructor with the elements, I get the error `no matching constructor for initialization of 'Vec3f' (aka 'Vector<float, 3>')`.

Everything similar question that I have looked at indicates that the constructors should automatically work with templated classes, so I'm not sure what is going on here. I previously had constructor errors with classes that didn't have a template specialization and it listed that the other constructor was not viable, which makes me think that the constructor isn't being copied to the templated class for some reason.

Comment: You really need to post more code than this...anyway, nothing from the primary template is copied over to a partial specialization, if that's what you are asking. They are completely unrelated.

Comment: I added the constructor code and everything that's in the specialization. If it's helpful to include something else, let me know.

Comment: @T.C. Does that mean that I have to copy all declarations and definitions of constructors, functions, operators, etc. from the template to the specialization? Is that not kind of defeating the purpose of templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial and explicit specializations do not inherit anything from the primary template; they are completely unrelated. In your code, a `Vector<T, 3>` is a completely empty class except for the static member function.

There are ways to reduce code duplication when a partial/explicit specialization share code with the primary template (for instance, by inheriting from a base class template that implements the shared functionality), but in this case I see no reason to write a partial specialization in the first place. Just make `cross` a free function template:

```
template <typename T, int DIMS>
class Vector
{
    // Default constructor
    Vector();
    // Data constructor
    Vector(const T data[DIMS]);

    // Other functions, variables, operators
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T, 3> cross(const Vector<T, 3> a, const Vector<T, 3> b);
```

As a side note, `Vector(const T data[DIMS]);` may not do what you think it does - it is exactly equivalent to `Vector(const T *data);`.

Comment: That fixes the issue. I read some other questions and it seemed like template members were copied to specializations. As far as your note, I am aware that those are equivalent; I just have that for the moment to clarify what should be passed.